# How to prevent memory consumption during collection enumeration?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, memory

In the following script:

```
    $pageSize = 1000;
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addWebsiteFilter($website->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    for ($currentPage = 1; $currentPage <= $pages; $currentPage++) {
        $productCollection->setCurPage($currentPage);

        foreach ($productCollection as $productItem) {
            $this->writeProductForStores($ioObject, $productItem, $stores, $defaultStore);
        }

        $productCollection->clear();
    }
```

Let's say I've processed page #1, now I'm on the page #2, processing products 1001-2000, and I don't need products 1-1000 from the first page, but they're still in the memory (I'm monitoring the script execution from top)! And the memory consumption grows as the execution goes, then falling with exception of surpassing the memory limit.

How do I clear memory after finishing processing the previous page?

Comment: What `$this->writeProductForStores()` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change how you iterate the collection.

Inchoo did a great write-up on the issue:

https://inchoo.net/magento/working-with-large-magento-collections/

Comment: I want to use pages. I believe, it's possible to achieve with usage of them, isn't it? I wouldn't like to write my own iterator every time I work with big collection - it seems to be an overwhelming approach.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use pages. I believe, it's possible to achieve with usage of them, isn't it? I wouldn't like to write my own iterator every time I work with big collection - it seems to be an overwhelming approach.

I agree with @ProxiBlue ... example code mentioned in Inchoos write-up work also in "standalone"-sripts ... and performs well on large collections ...

Examples:

- [For each loop running only once](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229381/for-each-loop-running-only-once/229425#229425)
- [Magento load huge collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178572/magento-load-huge-collection/178577#178577)

Comment: I agree that this approach is good, but... Can we achieve the same thing doing some magic with clearing products from the processed pages?

Comment: @NikitaAbrashnev I'm not sure what you mean with "pages" ? Something like bulk-operations? (I guess this code works also for several thousends of products.) May add some info to ypir question?

Comment: Yep, there're pages in my code in the question:) `$pageSize = 1000;` `$productCollection->setCurPage($currentPage);`

Comment: @NikitaAbrashnev I've seen this code. :) But why? Is it really neccessary?

Comment: I just think it's possible. I got an answer on my inital question, actually, and I'll pick the answer, but just for myself I wanna know why paginating doesn't really clear previous pages from the memory and how can I manually clear them (pages)?

Comment: @NikitaAbrashnev reminder for me ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106962/what-does-getloadedproductcollection-clear-do? Will check it tomorrow. :)

Comment: as you can see in my question, this method is already used, but it doesn't clean the memory of the running script

Answer (score -1):

This is what I normally do:

```
$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addWebsiteFilter($website->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->getAllIds();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $this->writeProductForStores($ioObject, $product, $stores, $defaultStore);
}
```

`getAllIds()` fetches all the IDs in one DB read but it requires loading the model *n* times. This is best when you need all the attributes of the model. The `walk()` example by Inchoo reads the DB *n* times but no loading of model. If you have `addAtributeToSelect` to limit the amount if info, the `walk()` method is more efficient.

Comment: Please do not recommend to load products in a loop.

Comment: May I know why?

Comment: Its one of the baddest things you can do. `load($id)` loads the whole product model an may lead to heavy memory consumption and load times.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with sv3n. I also want to add that there's no reason to reload the product inside of the cycle as you may add to select all the attributes you need on the collection itself before it's loaded. Example: $collection->addFieldToSelect('*') or $collection->addFieldToSelect('sku')

Comment: @kiatng some numbers from antother question ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179273/find-min-max-value-of-product-attribute-in-a-large-category/179275#179275

Comment: It is one of the biggest performance killers

Comment: Depending on the size of your results,  and memory setup allocated to PHP, this will just as well have out of memory issues. You simply have not encountered out of memory as your datasets is likely small.

Comment: I agree with the comments, and you can read that in the last few sentences in my original answer that I understand the concern. In the code snippet in the question, `writeProductForStores()` seems to imply that we need all the product attributes, and there may be observers listening to the load events, so loading within a loop may not be a horrible option. But if optimization is the goal, I'll go one step further and use only the interfaces in the resource singleton, which has a more direct access to the DB and can be made to bypass all sorts of steps including events.